# shopping cart, after click on Add to Cart Button : price gets added but showing zero amount

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined(…)**

Hello guys, I going to make some add to cart modal I got some reference from **codepen** example after that I did some changes at my side in code. later I run that and I got the above error
I don't know how to solved that I tried, but not solved..
**when I comment that line, code will work but that product cost showing empty in cart. just showing zero amount.**

error line at js : `price = parseFloat(x.price.split('₹')[1]);`

my customize codepen link : https://codepen.io/guenon/pen/VwaxXLJ

original codepen link : https://codepen.io/PurpleTigress/pen/eXPxxq

```js
/* get cart total from session on load */
updateCartTotal();

/* button event listeners */
document.getElementById("emptycart").addEventListener("click", emptyCart);
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('addtocart');
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    addToCart(this);
  });
}

/* ADD TO CART functions */

function addToCart(elem) {
  //init
  var sibs = [];
  var getprice;
  var getproductName;
  var cart = [];
  var stringCart;
  //cycles siblings for product info near the add button
  while (elem = elem.previousSibling) {
    if (elem.nodeType === 3) continue; // text node
    if (elem.className == "price") {
      getprice = elem.innerText;
    }
    if (elem.className == "productname") {
      getproductName = elem.innerText;
    }
    sibs.push(elem);
  }
  //create product object
  var product = {
    productname: getproductName,
    price: getprice
  };
  //convert product data to JSON for storage
  var stringProduct = JSON.stringify(product);
  /*send product data to session storage */

  if (!sessionStorage.getItem('cart')) {
    //append product JSON object to cart array
    cart.push(stringProduct);
    //cart to JSON
    stringCart = JSON.stringify(cart);
    //create session storage cart item
    sessionStorage.setItem('cart', stringCart);
    addedToCart(getproductName);
    updateCartTotal();
  } else {
    //get existing cart data from storage and convert back into array
    cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart'));
    //append new product JSON object
    cart.push(stringProduct);
    //cart back to JSON
    stringCart = JSON.stringify(cart);
    //overwrite cart data in sessionstorage 
    sessionStorage.setItem('cart', stringCart);
    addedToCart(getproductName);
    updateCartTotal();
  }
}
/* Calculate Cart Total */
function updateCartTotal() {
  //init
  var total = 0;
  var price = 0;
  var items = 0;
  var productname = "";
  var carttable = "";
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('cart')) {
    //get cart data & parse to array
    var cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart'));
    //get no of items in cart 
    items = cart.length;
    //loop over cart array
    for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
      //convert each JSON product in array back into object
      var x = JSON.parse(cart[i]);
      //get property value of price
      price = parseFloat(x.price.split('₹')[1]);
      productname = x.productname;
      //add price to total
      carttable += "<tr><td>" + productname + "</td><td>₹" + price.toFixed(2) + "</td></tr>";
      total += price;
    }

  }
  //update total on website HTML
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
  //insert saved products to cart table
  document.getElementById("carttable").innerHTML = carttable;
  //update items in cart on website HTML
  document.getElementById("itemsquantity").innerHTML = items;
}
//user feedback on successful add
function addedToCart(pname) {
  var message = pname + " was added to the cart";
  var alerts = document.getElementById("alerts");
  alerts.innerHTML = message;
  if (!alerts.classList.contains("message")) {
    alerts.classList.add("message");
  }
}
/* User Manually empty cart */
function emptyCart() {
  //remove cart session storage object & refresh cart totals
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('cart')) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('cart');
    updateCartTotal();
    //clear message and remove class style
    var alerts = document.getElementById("alerts");
    alerts.innerHTML = "";
    if (alerts.classList.contains("message")) {
      alerts.classList.remove("message");
    }
  }
}



$('.ticket-text').each(function() {
  var words = $(this).text().split(" ");
  var maxWords = 6;

  if (words.length > maxWords) {
    html = words.slice(0, maxWords) + '<span class="more_text" style="display:none;"> ' + words.slice(maxWords, words.length) + '</span>' + '<a href="#" class="read_more">...<br/>[Read More]</a>'

    $(this).html(html)

    $(this).find('a.read_more').click(function(event) {
      $(this).toggleClass("less");
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).html("<br/>[Read Less]")
        $(this).parent().find(".more_text").show();
      } else {
        $(this).html("...<br/>[Read More]")
        $(this).parent().find(".more_text").hide();
      }
    })

  }

})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700');
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  /*   background:#E0E4CC; */
  background: #69d2e7;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #69d2e7 0%, #a7dbd8 25%, #e0e4cc 46%, #e0e4cc 54%, #f38630 75%, #fa6900 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #69d2e7 0%, #a7dbd8 25%, #e0e4cc 46%, #e0e4cc 54%, #f38630 75%, #fa6900 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #69d2e7 0%, #a7dbd8 25%, #e0e4cc 46%, #e0e4cc 54%, #f38630 75%, #fa6900 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#69d2e7', endColorstr='#fa6900', GradientType=1);
}

hr {
  border: none;
  background: #E0E4CC;
  height: 1px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.productcont {
  display: grid;
}

.product {
  width: 310px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5PX rgba(229, 66, 64, 1);
  margin-right: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.cart-container {
  border: 1px solid #E0E4CC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

button,
input[type="submit"] {
  border: 1px solid #FA6900;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ed3330;
  padding: 0.6em 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 1.2em;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

button:hover,
button:focus,
button:active,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:active {
  background: #0894fc;
  border-color: black;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td,
table th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E4CC;
}

#carttotals {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.cart-buttons {
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

#emptycart {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

table td:nth-last-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}

.message {
  border-width: 1px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #A7DBD8;
  color: #679996;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.ticket-text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h1>Course Packages</h1><br>
  <div id="alerts"></div>
  <div class="productcont">
    <div class="product">
      <h3 class="productname">product name</h3>
      <p><strong>Class :</strong></p>
      <p><strong>Board :</strong></p>
      <p><strong>Subject :</strong></p>
      <p class="ticket-text">Bacsaddsadsad on ipsum dolor amet se vsc sadsadasdd addasd sfsd sdfsdf</p>
      <span class="price amount">₹ 5.05</span>
      <del><span class="offered_price amount">₹ 1000</span></del><br></br>
      <button class="addtocart">Add To Cart</button>
      <button class="buynow ">Buy Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cart-container">
    <h2>Cart</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><strong>Product</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Price</strong></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="carttable">
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table id="carttotals">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Items</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>x <span id="itemsquantity">0</span></td>
        <td>₹<span id="total">0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="cart-buttons">
      <button id="emptycart">Empty Cart</button>
      <button id="checkout">Checkout</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in you codepen when you assign multiple classes to element you should check whether class applied to that element or not using `classList`.

here is the link to [updated code](https://jsfiddle.net/67jsfmn2/)

```
 while ((elem = elem.previousSibling)) {
    if (elem.nodeType === 3) continue; // text node
    if (elem.className == "price")
   // instead of using above condition use either
    if(elem.classList.contains('price'))
   // or
    if(elem.className === "price amount") 

    {
      getprice = elem.innerText;
    }
    if (elem.className == "productname") {
      getproductName = elem.innerText;
    }
    sibs.push(elem);
  }
```

Comment: yeah there is two different class I added one is amount and another is price class is defined in javascript but amount class not defined cause this is bootstrap class

Comment: that is okay. i would suggest to use classList to find out the node which has price style applied to it irrespective of what other classes are applied to that element. using classList will always work and is less error prone.

Comment: still not working, I used above while loop that u have given still price showing zero after click on add to cart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221371/discussion-between-sandeep-joshi-and-brute).

Comment: @sandeepjoshi Can i get any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/335240/57334 thanks.

Answer (score 1):

class name of price of the product is incorrect. Check this link price is getting added

Here is the issue

```
<span class="price amount">₹ 5.05</span>
```

corrected below:
https://jsfiddle.net/h86cp4q2/

Change the following things

1.

```
<span class="price amount">₹ 5.05</span>
```

To

```
<span class="priceamount">₹ 5.05</span>
```

2. 

```
if(elem.className == "price"){
```

To

```
if(elem.className == "priceamount"){
```

[image: This shows the price of product]

Comment: the given link is wrong showing something different like map some kind of..

Comment: your given file is also not working, when I click on add to cart button happen nothing, check it..

Comment: check the updated answer, it's working for me @BruTe